# Cloudwatch dashboard Gauge widget shows as Line chart when shared public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a [CloudWatch Dashboard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Dashboards.html) and added Gauge widgets to it which look like this:

[image]

However when I share the dashboard what users see is instead a Line chart like this:

[image]

I don't see anything in the docs that specify Gauges can't be shared, is this a limitation when [sharing dashboards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-dashboard-sharing.html) or is there something else happening here that I'm missing?

Comment: I just a opened a support ticket for this, it looks like a bug

Comment: Did you get a response from support confirming that @TonyBenBrahim?

Comment: Also seeing this. @TonyBenBrahim did you get a response?

Comment: Yes, it is a known bug, it is on their backlog, with no ETA, I would suggest that anyone who sees this and has support with AWS file a support ticket so that this issue can be escalated in priority.

Comment: PARTIAL RESPONSE"We already have an internal ticket with our Dashboard teams and they have clarified that newer Visualisation Features (ex: widgets like Explorer and Gauge) are not supported by the current Shared Dashboards UI, however they are working to update it and anticipate these widgets to be implemented in the near future. Unfortunately I won’t be able to provide you with an ETA on when this feature might be released as I have no visibility over that process."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug and there is no ETA for a resolution, confirmed by @TonyBenBrahim in the comments above:

> PARTIAL RESPONSE "We already have an internal ticket with our Dashboard teams and they have clarified that newer Visualisation Features (ex: widgets like Explorer and Gauge) are not supported by the current Shared Dashboards UI, however they are working to update it and anticipate these widgets to be implemented in the near future. Unfortunately I won’t be able to provide you with an ETA on when this feature might be released as I have no visibility over that process."

If the bug is affecting you then raising a support ticket with AWS may lead to a fix being prioritised.